# Convertir string en HTML en Symfony

Tags: symfony

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de renderizar una cadena de texto (string) en etiquetas HTML. Esto me ocurre al usar un formulario, que tras enviar los datos los previsualiza, pero el problema es que no interpreta las etiquetas HTML, simplemente me las muestra.

La variable la paso a twig de esta forma:

```
return $this->render('registro/index.html.twig', array(
            'articulo' => $producto->getArticleHtml(),
        ));
```

`$producto` no es más que la instancia de una entidad que previamente he declarado, para luego poder subir a la base de datos.

Lo visualizo de esta forma en twig:

```
<p>{{ articulo }}</p>
```

¿Me estoy olvidando de algo? Es la primera vez que trabajo con Symfony y esto con PHP puro (sin usar ningún framework) me funcionaba sin ningún problema.

Ejemplo de cómo se muestra, con etiquetas incluidas:

```
<b>Esto es una prueba</b>
```

Comment: ¿Probaste usando la palabra clave `raw`?, algo así: **`<p>{{ articulo | raw }}</p>`** [Ver esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8355239/5587982), para más detalles.

Comment: @A.Cedano ¡Gracias! No encontraba la forma de hacerlo, y las respuestas de stackoverflow eran todas aplicando javascript. Concretamente la documentación estaría aquí por si a alguien le interesa: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/escaping.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usas plantilla `Twig` el escape de salida viene activado por defecto. Si quieres desactivarlo puedes hacerlo con `raw`, [tal y como dice la documentación](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/escaping.html):

> Si está usando plantillas Twig, entonces el escape de salida está
>   activado por defecto. Esto significa que está protegido de inmediato
>   contra las consecuencias involuntarias del código enviado por el
>   usuario. De forma predeterminada, el escape de salida supone que se
>   está escapando contenido para salida HTML.
>
> En algunos casos, deberá inhabilitar el escapado de salida cuando
>   represente una variable que sea de confianza y que contenga marcas que
>   no se deben escapar. Supongamos que los usuarios administrativos
>   pueden escribir artículos que contienen código HTML. Por defecto, Twig
>   escapará del cuerpo del artículo.
>
> Para renderizarlo normalmente, agregue el filtro sin formato:
>
> ```
> {{ article.body|raw }}
> ```
>
> También puede desactivar el escape de salida dentro de un área `{%
>   block%}` o para una plantilla completa. Para obtener más información,
>   vea [Salida de escape](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#escaper-extension) en la documentación de Twig.

Siguiendo estas indicaciones, tu código debería funcionar si haces esto:

```
<p>{{ articulo | raw }}</p>
```